# Why does a GDB watchpoint stop on an irrelevant line when swapping binary tree nodes?

Tags: c, gdb, binary-tree, valgrind, watchpoint

I am trying to swap two nodes `A` and `B` in a binary tree so that the places they are actually stored in memory change but the tree topology is not changed.  I added special handling for swapping a node with its parent, but it still seems that it doesn't work.  I'm using Valgrind with vgdb so that I can catch memory errors and also get consistent addresses.  If I have a tree like

```
78
  \
   40
  /  \
5c   c5
```

And then I try to swap `A=40` and `B=5c`, the links get messed up.  Specifically, `40->right`.  Setting a watchpoint on it (`watch -l`), I found that `40->right` is being set to `5c->right` (`NULL`) by `memcpy` as it should be, but then also that it is being changed to `A` later by `if(a_l.left == b){` which is clearly impossible.  I've had a watchpoint report the wrong line like this before when I was using `movq` instead of `movb` in assembly, but I'm pretty sure I have the sizes right this time because I didn't at first and it didn't make it through any swaps but I fixed it and now it makes it through around a dozen.  I sanity check the tree after every operation so the error is here.  Here is the simplest demonstration I could manage:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct avl_node avl_node;
struct avl_node{
    avl_node *left, *right, *parent;
    signed char balance;
    char data[];
};

avl_node *avl_root(avl_node *n){
    while(n && n->parent){
        n = n->parent;
    }
    return n;
}

inline static int avl_check_links(avl_node *n){
    if(!n)return 1;
    if(n->left){
        if(n->left->parent != n){
            return 0;
        }
        if(!avl_check_links(n->left)){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if(n->right){
        if(n->right->parent != n){
            return 0;
        }
        if(!avl_check_links(n->right)){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void avl_swap_nodes(avl_node *a, avl_node *b, size_t size){
    avl_node a_l = *a, b_l = *b;
    char tmp[sizeof(avl_node) + size];
    memcpy(tmp, a, sizeof(avl_node) + size);
    memcpy(a, b, sizeof(avl_node) + size);
    memcpy(b, tmp, sizeof(avl_node) + size);
    if(a_l.left){
        a_l.left->parent = b;
    }
    if(a_l.right){
        a_l.right->parent = b;
    }
    if(b_l.left){
        b_l.left->parent = a;
    }
    if(b_l.right){
        b_l.right->parent = a;
    }
    if(a_l.parent){
        if(a_l.parent->left == a){
            a_l.parent->left = b;
        }else{
            a_l.parent->right = b;
        }
    }
    if(b_l.parent){
        if(b_l.parent->left == b){
            b_l.parent->left = a;
        }else{
            b_l.parent->right = a;
        }
    }
    if(a_l.parent == b){
        if(b_l.left == a){
            b->left = a_l.left;
            a->left = b;
        }else{
            b->right = a_l.right;
            a->right = b;
        }
        a->parent = b_l.parent;
        b->parent = a;
    }else if(b_l.parent == a){//GDB stops here on a watch -l a->right
        if(a_l.left == b){
            a->left = b_l.left;
            b->left = a;
        }else{
            a->right = b_l.right;
            b->right = a;
        }
        b->parent = a_l.parent;
        a->parent = b;
    }
    assert(avl_check_links(avl_root(a)));
    assert(avl_check_links(avl_root(b)));
}

int main(void){
    avl_node a, b, c, d;
    a = (avl_node){.right=&b};
    b = (avl_node){.left=&c, .right=&d, .parent=&a};
    c = (avl_node){.parent=&b};
    d = (avl_node){.parent=&b};
    assert(avl_check_links(avl_root(&a)));
    avl_swap_nodes(&b, &c, 0);
}
```

Why does GDB stop on the wrong line?  I think it may have to do with the fact that I am using vgdb: it also skips some lines when I single step.  Also why is `a->right` changed a second time at all?  Thank you.

You can get this file to run with reasonably recent versions of gcc, gdb, and valgrind by doing `gcc -g -o main main.c`, `valgrind --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 ./main&`, `gdb main`, `tar rem | vgdb`, `b avl_swap_nodes`, `c`, `watch -l a->right`, and then get rid of the vgdb process neatly by doing `c` repeatedly and then `Ctrl-d` or `kill` and then `Ctrl-d`.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisations? GDB can only stop on lines that actually exist in the compiled program. In general you want to turn off optimisations during the debug stage of development.

Comment: Given that you `memcpy()` pointers inside of the structs, some of which might refer to the other struct, `restrict`ing the parameters might be incorrect.

Comment: @jforberg I'm using -g and no optimizations

Comment: @EOF So `restrict` means there are no other pointer to that thing, not just no other pointers in the arguments?

Comment: @hacatu: `restrict` means that the pointed-to object(s) will not be accessed by any expression not based on the `restrict`ed pointer if they are accessed by the `restrict`ed pointer. Whether the `memcpy()` counts as "based on" might be a language-lawyer worthy question.

Comment: I took out `restrict` just in case but I still get the same thing.

Comment: @hacatu please add your main() function so we can compile and try to reproduce?

Comment: I'll write one up and add it (this is taken from an excessively complicated program that attempts to provide a cache using a heap of avl nodes).

Comment: @hacatu Please do. We prefer to see a minimal failing example, ideally something you can just copy paste into a file and compile. This makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: I've updated my question to have a useable main() and instructions on what valgrind and gdb commands I used.

Comment: on linux 14.04 I compiled via: `gcc -c -ggdb -std=gnu99 -o untitled.o  untitled.c`   then linked with `gcc -ggdb untitled.o -o untitled`  then ran with `gdb untitled`   Stepping through the code, I noticed that the recursion was VERY deep and eventually caused a seg fault event.  However, the only skipped lines were when some `if` code block was not entered, because the `if` condition failed.  I.E. the code logic is wrong, but `gdb` did exactly as expected

Comment: @user3629249 I don't get that even when I build in the manner you describe.  I think the lines being skipped is an artifact of using Valgrind for me.  Also, I think that you actually have basically the same error as I do except that for you whatever ghost write is tripping the watchpoint makes `b->parent` point to `b` as well as `b->right` so that `avl_check_nodes` cannot find an error.  This makes me think that the problem may be related to struct packing.

Comment: Well indeed `sizeof(avl_node) > offsetof(avl_node, data)` so the discrepancy in the manifestation of the error is likely due to this, but replacing that does not solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and it isn't fun so I'm going to answer my own question.  The node swapping code is wrong.  Here is a version that works

```
#include <stddef.h>
void avl_swap_nodes(avl_node *a, avl_node *b, size_t size){
    avl_node a_l = *a, b_l = *b;
    char tmp[offsetof(avl_node, data) + size];
    memcpy(tmp, a, offsetof(avl_node, data) + size);
    memcpy(a, b, offsetof(avl_node, data) + size);
    memcpy(b, tmp, offsetof(avl_node, data) + size);
    if(a_l.parent == b){
        if(b_l.left == a){
            a->left = b;
        }else{
            a->right = b;
        }
        b->parent = a;
        if(a->parent){
            if(a->parent->left == b){
                a->parent->left = a;
            }else{
                a->parent->right = a;
            }
        }
    }else if(b_l.parent == a){
        if(a_l.left == b){
            b->left = a;
        }else{
            b->right = a;
        }
        a->parent = b;
        if(b->parent){
            if(b->parent->left == a){
                b->parent->left = b;
            }else{
                b->parent->right = b;
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(a->parent){
            if(b->parent == a->parent){
                if(a->parent->left == b){
                    a->parent->left = a;
                    b->parent->right = b;
                }else{
                    a->parent->right = a;
                    b->parent->left = b;
                }
            }else{
                if(a->parent->left == b){
                    a->parent->left = a;
                }else{
                    a->parent->right = a;
                }
            }
        }
        if(b->parent && b->parent != a->parent){
            if(b->parent->left == a){
                b->parent->left = b;
            }else{
                b->parent->right = b;
            }
        }
    }
    if(a->left){
        a->left->parent = a;
    }
    if(a->right){
        a->right->parent = a;
    }
    if(b->left){
        b->left->parent = b;
    }
    if(b->right){
        b->right->parent = b;
    }
    ASSERT_ALL(avl_root(a));
    ASSERT_ALL(avl_root(b));
}
```

The reason why GDB is reporting the watchpoint on the wrong line is because a previous memory write overflows.  This can happen for example when you use `movq` instead of `movb` in assembly,  or when you do `char a; ((int*)&a) = (int)0;` in C, or when you `memcpy` more than you meant to.  This last one is what is causing problems in my code.  Consider the struct `struct A{int a; char b[];);`.  `sizeof(struct A)` is probably 8 because of structure padding, but `offsetof(struct A, b)` is probably 4.  Therefore if we calculate the size of the `struct A` together with the data in the flexible array at the end by adding the data size to `sizeof(struct A)`, we will calculate a value 4 bytes greater than it should be.  The solution is to use `offsetof(struct A, b);` instead.

The reason why GDB is skipping lines is because I was using `valgrind --vgdb=yes` instead of `valgrind --vgdb=full`.